# Create hash from XSD without an XML Example Using XML::Compile

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

I want to 1) create a hash *structure* based on my XSD definition file, 2) initialize the elements of that hash, then 3) write out an XML file. Here's where I'm at:

What I've managed to do is create a hash, but I'm doing it by reading in an example XML file--I'm doing this because I'm following code examples I've found, but I think the examples are trying to accomplish something other than what I need to do. I simply need to know what the hash looks like to I can set values of its elements, I don't want or need to know what a particular hash initialized would look like for some arbitrary XML file.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Compile::Schema;
use File::Spec;
use File::Copy;
use Getopt::Long;
use String::Util;

my $xsd          = 'My_XMLSchema.xsd';
my $xml_in       = 'example.xml';

my $schema       = XML::Compile::Schema->new($xsd);
my $reader       = $schema->compile(READER => '{http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd}RootElement');

my $hash         = $reader->($xml_in);
my $doc         = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $write       = $schema->compile(WRITER => '{http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd}RootElement');
my $xml_out     = $write->($doc, $hash);
```

If I were to

print Dumper $hash

the output is the code I would write if I wanted to *create* the XML file I've provided--that's not what I need. I just want to generate my $hash so I can then stick data values in it and create an XML. Seems I should need only and XSD file to do this. Does this make sense?

I don't understand what $reader actually *is*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data structure with the same structure as your sample data. 
The sample XML file can be used as an inspiration on how the data structure should look like, but is not needed in the final program.

Here is an example based on the [sample schema from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Compile::Schema;

my $xsd          = 'shiporder.xsd';
my $xml_in       = 'shiporder.xml';

my $schema       = XML::Compile::Schema->new($xsd);

# This can be removed for production
# as the output serves only as an inspiration for $real_hash
{
    my $reader       = $schema->compile(READER => 'shiporder');
    my $sample_hash = $reader->($xml_in);

    print Dumper( $sample_hash );
}

# a hashref just like $sample_hash, but with my data
my $real_hash = {
          'orderid' => '42',
          'shipto' => {
                      'address' => 'Lindenstrasse 23',
                      'city' => 'Munich',
                      'country' => 'Germany',
                      'name' => 'Max Mustermann',
                    },
          'item' => [
                    {
                      'quantity' => '1',
                      'price' => bless( {
                                        '_es' => '-',
                                        '_e' => [
                                                  1
                                                ],
                                        '_m' => [
                                                  109
                                                ],
                                        'sign' => '+'
                                      }, 'Math::BigFloat' ),
                      'title' => 'dog feed',
                      'note' => 'delicious'
                    },
                    {
                      'price' => bless( {
                                        '_m' => [
                                                  99
                                                ],
                                        '_e' => [
                                                  1
                                                ],
                                        '_es' => '-',
                                        'sign' => '+'
                                      }, 'Math::BigFloat' ),
                      'title' => 'Enjoy',
                      'quantity' => '1'
                    }
                  ],
          'orderperson' => 'Martina Musterfrau'
        };

my $doc         = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $write       = $schema->compile(WRITER => 'shiporder');
my $xml_out     = $write->($doc, $real_hash);
print "\n";
print $xml_out;
```

Comment: Thanks. The hash structure is already created--that was done for me using XML::Compile. The examples that I've used to create the hash appears to make use of both the XSD schema definition file, AND a sample XML file. I'm trying to understand if the sample file is really needed, and if so, why. It doesn't make sense to me that I really need to use the XML, when the XSD is already provided.

Comment: I have edited my answer, clarifying that the reading of the sample file can be removed.